# logical error in python script, stuck on indentation

Tags: python, data-processing

The goals of this script are simple:

- read in a `.csv` file
- strip out instances of the escape character `&` and replace it with `&amp;`
- eliminate all rows that don't satisfy the following criteria:

  - validate the lines to ensure that they have no more or less columnar values than necessary
  - if possessed on a blank/null/whitespace/empty column- eliminate that row

The code looks like this:

```
import csv

num_headers = 9
starts = 1

def url_escaper(data):
  for line in data:
    yield line.replace('&','&amp;')

with open("adzuna_input.csv", 'r') as file_in, open("adzuna_output.csv", 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader(url_escaper(file_in))
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out)

    for i, row in enumerate(csv_in, starts):

        counter = 1
        if len(row) == num_headers:
            for element in row:
                if element.strip():
                    counter += 1
            if counter == num_headers:
                    csv_out.writerow(row)


        else:
            print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

earlier, I had it working but this last condition, i.e. *if possessed on a blank/null/whitespace/empty column- eliminate that row* is giving me trouble, I don't know what to do about it.

My solution was

```
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_in, starts):

        counter = 1
        if len(row) == num_headers:
            for element in row:
                if element.strip():
                    counter += 1
```

counting the rows, looking at the values, trying to `strip` them as a way of accessing whether or not this field has some useful information, i.e. a string/int/some text, in it.

However this is not working.

The exact error message I'm getting is about the indentation of `csv_out.writerow(row)`, but I suspect that is just a pretext.

**Exact message**

```
File validator.py, 
line 23 csv_out.writerow(row) 
               ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I would like to know why the above program does not execute.

Comment: *"I suspect that is just a pretext"* - Python isn't trying to flirt with you, give a [mcve] and the actual traceback.

Comment: It seems like not all of your code is posted. I don't see `csv_out.writerow(row)` anywhere.

Comment: good call, I accidently `ctrl + x`'d it when I wrote that last line

Comment: but no, because only print it if it satisfied a further condition- isn't it? and the determination of that criteria does indeed start on the `for element` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to format your code properly:

```
        for element in row:
            if element.strip():
                counter += 1
        if counter == num_headers:
                csv_out.writerow(row)
```

The line with `csv_out.writerow` is indented with 8 spaces, so whether `if is underindented` or `csv_out.writerow` is overindented.

Comment: While there clearly is an error in the indentation of the code, it must be due to having mixed spaces and tabs. The indentation shown, done purely with spaces, is in fact perfectly valid (just poor style). The `for` and the second `if` are separate, independent blocks of code, each of which is allowed to be indented by whatever amount.